# How can I prevent https

Tags: php, https

I have a website that can be accessed both with http and https.
The website has a form that brings the user to another site on another server.
So when I use https and the form is submitted, I get a warning that the data are being sent insecurely.

The second server does not support https, so I figured that the fastest and easiest is to prevent the first website from being accessed through https.

Is there a way to do that (with PHP for example)?

Comment: You're not submitting any senstive information or passwords, are you?

Comment: Haha, good question. :D  No, the form contains nothing that is sensitive or so.

Comment: The title is so funny, like you want to prevent security...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do in this case is check the HTTPS status on your form page, and redirect to HTTP if necessary:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') {
    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I tried that already but it does not work. The browser alerts the user that the connection is insecure as it is not sent with https.

Comment: That must be what he is already doing: *"brings the user to another site on another server"*

Comment: Thanks Chris, I tried that but I get an error saying that the site isn't redirecting properly (endless loop). I wonder how this is possible, as there is nothing on that site that redirects anything.  edit: nevermind, it was just firefox.... works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

(This goes into your .htaccess file)

Comment: Thanks. How can I write it in a way that it only applies to the specific webpage with the form? For example the file name is form.php  Can the above be applied only to form.php?

Comment: don't forget to include the 301 so that search engines will know to use the `http` version in the future. and @koljanep if you do that you will scare the hell out of your users. "im only secure until im sending information" is a bad thought to have.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea I don't follow what you mean by that. Of course I would scare the hell out of people if I would present a "secure site", just to then direct them onto a non-secure site. That's exactly what I try to avoid. You see, on server 1 I have both https as well as http available, so I don't care which one is used. The information are not sensitive. However, Server 2 has no https setup. In that case I am forced to use the http as well on server 1 to make sure I don't get a scary alert box from the browser. So, that said, how can I do that? NOTE: I want the mod_rw to apply only to this site

Comment: @koljanep what I mean is that on site 1, how u r describing it, every page except the form page would be in HTTPS, and then on the form page it would be HTTP. if you were navigating a site that was entirely on SSL, and then you went to one page with a form that was suddenly standard HTTP ... yes, that would scare users. your best (only standards-based?) option is to make the **entire site** HTTP-based. if you have a secure section you need, then make THAT section HTTPS and everything else HTTP. Trust me, that will be a lot better.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea okay, I got it. Yes that was my plan, but I just did not want to disable https for the entire location, but merely for this one script. If someone decides to access any other page with https, that is up to them of course.